# Could a shiny app containing `reactivePoll` continue to work, with no session present?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

My app (hosted on shinyapps.io) uses `reactivePoll` to check a database table and when the data change it sends me a mail.

The app works fine when there is at least one session open, but stops when there are no users connected.

On the help for `reactivePoll` I read:

*session

The user session to associate this file reader with, or NULL if none. If non-null, the reader will automatically stop when the session ends.*

So, I used reactivePoll like this, hoping it would continue to work when no one is connected.

`reactivePoll(2000, session=NULL, isThereNewFile, loadData)`

However, when all end user sessions disconnect, reactivePoll stops working. (The `loadData` function sends me a mail, so I know it doesn't work because I don't get any mails). Is there a way to have the app running, when no session is present? what is the meaning of `session=NULL`?

Comment: If there is no UI interaction needed (just checking for changes and sending mails) I'd start a background R session via library([callr](https://github.com/r-lib/callr)) from your global app part (in fact shiny isn't  necessary for this at all).

Comment: @ismirsehregal I would be interested in alternative ways to do that, even without shiny (but using R).